# Visual Studio Code doesn't follow maven goal

Tags: java, maven, visual-studio-code

I'm working with a Java project and *Visual Studio Code* as a IDE. This project make use of [ActiveJDBC](https://javalite.io/activejdbc). ActiveJDBC requires [instrumentation](https://javalite.io/instrumentation) of class files after they are compiled. Usually this is done with a maven plugin that start in the *process-classes* phase.

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.javalite</groupId>
    <artifactId>activejdbc-instrumentation</artifactId>
    <version>${activejdbc.version}</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>process-classes</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>instrument</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

My workflow with VSC is simply to change the source code and run/debug/test the project. As far as I know VSC compile the java files every time I save, but doesn't follow the maven rules and so, it didn't run the instrumentation process.

I would like to press F5 (debug the project) without having to remeber to call the instrumentation if a modify some class of the model. Any suggestion?

Comment: Any chance you can share a sample project?